# How to fix the jquery ui bug?

Tags: jquery, css, firebug

I have a bug in my code, not really sure where its located but it seems to sterm from my jquery css library please check this image  :[image]

i get a "syntax" error when i debug my application using fire bug and the error is directed at line 9 OF my jquery css library which is the following:[image]

but i'm struggling to identify the actual problem. please anyone with any piece of help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Instead of images please directly copy the error message and code. This makes it very unreadable as it is

Comment: How are you including your CSS into the page?

Comment: I included it at the header of my html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a problem with the comments above line 9 - maybe an invalid char or something.
Things I'd consider doing:

1. Download the css file again (replace original).
2. Remove the comments above line 9.

Cheers and Good Luck